# How to create web-services in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How to create web services over HTTP REST protocol using Zend Framework 2 (third party)

We use this code in Zend Framework 1 :

```
        <?php
        function methodName($name) {
        echo "Hello world - $name";
        }

        $server = new Zend_Rest_Server();
        $server->addFunction('methodName');
        $server->handle();
        ?>
```

An example code will be useful.

Comment: what did you tried so far ? Ask how to does not fill the requirements for a good question

Comment: @Hooli I am new in ZF2, If you can,please help me. i want use third party libraries in pure php project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good start could be to look at the [Apigility](https://apigility.org/documentation) Project